# getting strange error while calculating z-score

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, statistics, data-science

i want to calculate z-score of my whole dataset. i have tried two types of code but unfortunately they both gave me the same error.
my 1 code is here:

```
zee=stats.zscore(df)
print(zee)
```

my 2 code is:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
z = np.abs(stats.zscore(df))
print(z)
```

am using jupyter

The error i have got:

```
-----
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-ef429aebacfd> in <module>
      1 from scipy import stats
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 z = np.abs(stats.zscore(df))
      4 print(z)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in zscore(a, axis, ddof, nan_policy)
   2495         sstd = np.nanstd(a=a, axis=axis, ddof=ddof, keepdims=True)
   2496     else:
-> 2497         mns = a.mean(axis=axis, keepdims=True)
   2498         sstd = a.std(axis=axis, ddof=ddof, keepdims=True)
   2499 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
    160     ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
    161     if isinstance(ret, mu.ndarray):
--> 162         ret = um.true_divide(
    163                 ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
    164         if is_float16_result and out is None:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

and here the info of my dataframe,if theres something wrong with my datafarme.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 14 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------          --------------  -----  
 0   Region          100 non-null    object 
 1   Country         100 non-null    object 
 2   Item Type       100 non-null    object 
 3   Sales Channel   100 non-null    object 
 4   Order Priority  100 non-null    object 
 5   Order Date      100 non-null    object 
 6   Order ID        100 non-null    int64  
 7   Ship Date       100 non-null    object 
 8   Units Sold      100 non-null    int64  
 9   Unit Price      100 non-null    float64
 10  Unit Cost       100 non-null    float64
 11  Total Revenue   100 non-null    float64
 12  Total Cost      100 non-null    float64
 13  Total Profit    100 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(5), int64(2), object(7)
memory usage: 11.1+ KB
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: well from the traceback it seems that you're trying to calculate zscore for a column that's either str or mixed (str and floats), instead of int / float. check your dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your df contains non `float/int` values, please try sending only int/float cols to your zscore func.

```py
stats.zscore(df[['Unit Cost', 'Total Revenue', 'Total Cost', 'Total Profit']])
```